# "expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token" when calling overloaded "<<" with customized data type

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a simple class 'A' with the following contents:

```
class A {
public:
    struct data_t {
        int32_t val;
    
        data_t(int32_t _val) :
            val(_val) {
            ;
        };
    };

    A& operator << (const data_t &data) {
        printf("[%s] %d\n", __func__, data.val);
        return *this;
    };

    void func(const data_t &data) {
        printf("[%s] %d\n", __func__, data.val);
    }
};
```

I tried the following codes and got:

```
A a;

a<<{100};          //"expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token" 
a<<A::data_t{100}; //OK.
a.func({100});     //OK.
```

Why a<<{100}; is NG and a.func({100}); is OK?

I don't want to use the second sentence because it is too long and complicated to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why a<<{100}; is NG and a.func({100}); is OK?

The grammar of the language simply only allows braced initializer lists in certain places. As operand to (arithmetic) operators in expressions it is generally not allowed, even thought one might be able to make sense of it for overloaded operators.

Braced initializer lists are potentially allowed:

- in initializers of variables, class members, `new` expressions, default arguments (for function parameters and non-type template parameters)
- after a type specifier (functional type conversion notation)
- as arguments in function calls and template arguments
- as right-hand side of assignment
- as operand to `return`, `co_return` and `co_yield`
- as initializer in a range-`for`

Assuming I didn't forget any case, they cannot be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Since `A::data_t` has a *conversion constructor* (a non-explicit single-argument constructor) the compiler can do implicit conversions from `int32_t` to `A::data_t`.

That means you can simply do e.g.

```
a << 100;
```

Comment: If I modify A::data_t such like
    struct data_t {
        int32_t v0;
        double v1;
    
        data_t(int32_t _v0, double _v1) :
            v0(_v0),
            v1(_v1) {
            ;
        };
    };
Obviously there is no conversion constructor for A:: data_t but I can still not use a<<{100, 1.2};

Comment: @BruceHsu obviously ? `data_t(int32_t,double)` is a converting constructor. Anyhow, this answer says that you can use the converting constructor, that doesnt imply that by removing it your approach will work